# C- conversion type character '0' and '[' in format [-Wformat=] and too many arguments

Tags: c

I'm having trouble with two errors. I've searched on the site and have found that the conversion type character and too many arguments errors are coming from `sscanf` and `printf`, which occur on lines 166 and 186 in my code.

The code processes bits of information (like name, city, state, DOB, email address, etc) collected from a text file. I believe it has something to do with my `%` signs or the bracket format `[^\n]`. I saw another post where certain characters were defined inside the bracket like this: `%40[A-Za-z0-9._@] %[A-Za-z ]` but I have no idea if that is what I need to do to solve at least the unknown conversion type character issue. Any help would be appreciated.
The variables are declared in my .h file, but the lowercase letters before the name (`c`, `sz`, and `i`) represent char, char array, and integer.

Here is part of the code where the errors are supposedly originating from. I commented out a return statement because the method this code is used in is void:

```
    iScanfCnt = sscanf(szInputBuffer, "%1c %1s %4s %30[^\n] %30[^\n] %2s %2s %5s %s %d\n"
    , &customer.cGender
    , customer.szBirthDt
    , customer.szEmailAddr
    , customer.szFullName
    , customer.szStreetAddress
    , customer.szCity
    , customer.szStateCd
    , customer.szZipCd
    , flight.szFlightId
    , &flight.iRequestSeats);

    // Check for bad input.  scanf returns the number of valid conversions
    if (iScanfCnt < 10)
    {
        printf("invalid input when reading student data, only %d valid values. \n"
            , iScanfCnt);
        printf("\tdata is %s\n", szInputBuffer);
        //return ERR_MISSING_SWITCH;
    }
    printf("%1s %10.2s %10.2s %30[^n] %30[^n] %10.2s %2s %5s %s %d\n"
            , &customer.cGender
            , customer.szBirthDt
            , customer.szEmailAddr
            , customer.szFullName
            , customer.szStreetAddress
            , customer.szCity
            , customer.szStateCd
            , customer.szZipCd
            , flight.szFlightId
            , &flight.iRequestSeats);
}
```

And my errors:

```
p1xxxxxx.c: In function 'processReservations':

p1xxxxxx.c:166:4: warning: unknown conversion type character '0' in format [-Wformat=]
    , &flight.iRequestSeats);
    ^

p1xxxxxx.c:166:4: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]

p1xxxxxx.c:186:5: warning: unknown conversion type character '[' in format [-Wformat=]
     , &flight.iRequestSeats);
     ^

p1xxxxxx.c:186:5: warning: unknown conversion type character '[' in format [-Wformat=]

p1xxxxxx.c:186:5: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. One problem is that you can't use %[ in the printf format (and incidentally ^n is missing a backslash.). Use %s (or %.*s or %.<n>s). It would help us a lot if you would indicate which lines are lines 166 and 186. And please remove chitchat like introductions and thanks from questions.

Comment: Also for the `printf` : I don't think you want `&flight.iRequestSeats` - probably just `flight.iRequestSeats`. Same goes for `cGender`

Comment: "I commented out a return statement because the method this code is used in is void" -- I think you still want to return; you just don't want to return a value.

Comment: The problem is not in the `sscanf()` statement — or, at least, given a moderate facsimile of your customer and flight structures, the code in the `sscanf()` compiles cleanly.  The second set of messages looks like it belongs to a second `printf()` statement 20 lines after the one you show.  Surely you can get line numbers out of your editor to find out which lines are the ones that are causing you trouble.

Comment: And just a note on your `sscanf`, while you are free to read all sizes as string input, if seems much more logical for `sscanf` to handle the conversion to numeric form rather than doing it in a separate call later. If you are simply printing the information, it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin No sizes are being read. sz is Hungarian for zero-terminated string.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a working example of your code

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct x
{
    char cGender;
    char szBirthDt[200];
    char szEmailAddr[200];
    char szFullName[200];
    char szStreetAddress[200];
    char szCity[200];
    char szStateCd[200];
    char szZipCd[200];

};

struct y
{
    char szFlightId[200];
    int iRequestSeats;
};

int main(void) {
    struct x customer;
    struct y flight;
    int iScanfCnt;
    char* szInputBuffer = "m a bbbb cccccc\nsome text\nde fg hijkl mnop 10";

    iScanfCnt = sscanf(szInputBuffer, "%1c %1s %4s %30[^\n] %30[^\n] %2s %2s %5s %s %d\n"
    , &customer.cGender
    , customer.szBirthDt
    , customer.szEmailAddr
    , customer.szFullName
    , customer.szStreetAddress
    , customer.szCity
    , customer.szStateCd
    , customer.szZipCd
    , flight.szFlightId
    , &flight.iRequestSeats);

    if (iScanfCnt < 10)
    {
        printf("invalid input when reading student data, only %d valid values. \n"
            , iScanfCnt);
        printf("\tdata is %s\n", szInputBuffer);
        return -1;
    }

// Fix:      %c                 %s   %s
    printf("%1c %10.2s %10.2s %30s %30s %10.2s %2s %5s %s %d\n"
            , customer.cGender  // Fix: no &
            , customer.szBirthDt
            , customer.szEmailAddr
            , customer.szFullName
            , customer.szStreetAddress
            , customer.szCity
            , customer.szStateCd
            , customer.szZipCd
            , flight.szFlightId
            , flight.iRequestSeats);    // Fix: no &

    return 0;
}
```

I only needed to fix the `printf` - the `sscanf`worked fine.

Output:

```
m          a         bb                         cccccc                      some text         de fg hijkl mnop 10
```

See https://ideone.com/ipAHIb

Comment: Sure you couldn't have made a bit closer an educated guess on the array sizes in `x`. `200` seems a bit much for `%1s %4s %30[^\n] %30[^\n] %2s %2s %5s`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - Sure but it wasn't the important part here. The question tells nothing about the structures used and nothing about how memory is allocated (static/dynamic) so I just picked the fastest way to show how the compilation could be fixed.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Who the heck cares? That's completely irrelevant. It's just there to get the code to compile. The OP already has the correct definitions.

Comment: Thanks for all these great answers everyone. I got a lot more help than I expected. I'm working all day today but will try the proposed solution as soon as I can (probably when I go on my break). :D